# ASP.NET Streaming PDF bytestream - how to set document title?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, arrays

When streaming a pdf from ASP.NET (MVC2) to Chrome, I want to be able to set the caption that appears in the browser title (specifically, the Chrome tab caption).

I am generating my response as follows:

```
HttpContext.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("title", documentName);
HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;
HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(docStream);
HttpContext.Response.Flush();
```

where, typically, contentType is something like "application/pdf".

When viewed in Chrome, the caption of the Chrome tab is the full url of the document.  I just want it set to the document title.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [host the pdf inside a frame](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/iframe-pdf.html). This way you can set the title of the containing html page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a file name?

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyTitle.pdf");
```

Comment: Too bad, I wasn't sure how Chrome would behave, but worth a try.